# How to change values in app.php CakePHP permanently

Tags: cakephp, installation, cakephp-3.0

I'm writing Installer for 'CakePHP' application to provide easy way for user to install it. I'm trying to update 'Data source' values by following way

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
Configure::load('app', 'default');

Configure::write('Datasources.default.username', 'root');
```

But I read somewhere that it does not write value permanently in file. So what is the right way to update these values permanently in 'CakePHP'.

Comment: You want to read the whole page, but start with that chapter http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#reading-and-writing-configuration-files

Comment: @burzum thanks for sharing this one. This one is describing how to create new config files or dump data in our own config files. Is there no option to change values of existing config (app.php). I just need to update values for 'Datasource'

Comment: I just tried this one 
Configure::dump('Datasources', 'default', ['username', 'root']);
but no luck

Comment: Because of `ConnectionManager::config(Configure::consume('Datasources'));` You need to write the config in your own config file and then use the ConnectionManager to check, if required drop and (re-)configure connections. Read what consume() does.